# Jasmine - Restart browser between tests (it blocks)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, jasmine2.0

In our Protractor+Jasmine framework trying to restart browser between tests for different login user. As we have non-angular login page and after login its navigate to angular page. Following is my main test spec file

```js
describe('User Permissions', function() {
 var docsLoginPage = require('../pages/CLM_Page.js');
 var projectsPage = require('../pages/Projects_Page.js');
 var contentPage = require('../pages/Content_Page.js');
 
 beforeEach(function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  browser.get('http://be-docs-dev.xyz.local/');
   });
 
   it('Verify permissions for Non Admin and Read only permission group user', function() {
    docsLoginPage.loginToDocs("sipqa4@xyz.com","Yahoo@123");
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('abc');
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    expect(projectsPage.checkElementExistsById('headers_nav_projects')).toBe(false);
    expect(contentPage.checkElementExistsById("content_browse_options_folder_settings")).toBe(false);
    expect(contentPage.checkElementExistsById('content_browse_options_new_menu')).toBe(false);   
   });
  
     it('Verify permissions for Project collaborator Non Admin and Read only permission group user', function() {
      /*browser.restart().then(function(){
       console.log("-----------Restarted the browser---------------");
      });*/
    docsLoginPage.loginToDocs("sipqa2@xyz.com","Yahoo@123");
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('abc');
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    expect(projectsPage.checkElementExistsById('headers_nav_content')).toBe(false);
    expect(contentPage.checkElementExistsById("projects_browse_options_folder_settings")).toBe(false);
    expect(contentPage.checkElementExistsById('projects_browse_options_new_menu')).toBe(false);
    
   });
   
 });
```

And CLM_Page.js

```js
var CLM_page = function() {
 this.userName = element(By.id('userName'));
 this.password = element(By.id('password'));
 this.signIn = element(By.className('btn btn-primary'));
 this.loginToDocs = function(userName, password) {
  browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
  browser.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000);
  this.userName.sendKeys(userName);
  this.signIn.click();
  this.password.sendKeys(password);
  return this.signIn.click();
   };     
};
module.exports = new CLM_page();
```

In conf file set to

> restartBrowserBetweenTests: true

First it block is executing correctly. However while executing second it block browser restarting and closing immediately. Showing following error

> Failures:
>   1) User Permissions Verify permissions for Project collaborator Non Admin and Read only permission group user
>     Message:
>       Failed: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.
>     Stack:
>       NoSuchSessionError: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.

Comment: This might help: https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.restart

Comment: Is there no logout button which would take you back to the main login page?

Comment: @Barney- I tried browser.restart(). But its failing with non-angular login page.

Comment: @DublinDev- i tried almost all solutions suggested by google. Nothing worked for me. As a work around i am using logout now :(

Answer (score 0):

Based on your test case design, you can achieve the same by setting `restartBrowserBetweenTests: false` in `conf.js` file

And also clear the browser cookies and session from the browser after each `it` block run. Please modify your existing test script by adding [`afterEach`](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown)

add the below snippet with existing code

```
afterEach(function () {

  browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
  browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();window.localStorage.clear();');

});
```

`beforeEach` function should be like

```
beforeEach(function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.get('http://be-docs-dev.xyz.local/');
});
```

In `conf.js`.

`Note:` Default value is `false`. So it is not mandatory to set it as `false`

```
exports.config = {

 ...
 restartBrowserBetweenTests: false,
 ...
}
```

If you are setting `restartBrowserBetweenTests: true`, This will cause your tests to slow down drastically. Please refer [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5d29112fdea74ce4e5edb324b6243fdb07ca8229/lib/config.ts#L549)

Comment: @jithinkmatthew- Tried your solution but browser still remains in same first user logged in instance and trying to find login page

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the webdriver session is closed after starting the test.

There is no problem with `restartBrowserBetweenTests: true`, Since your browser is restarted after the first test.

Since you are moving from non angular to angular application. Follow as below

```
  browser.driver.get('http://localhost:8000/login.html');
  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys('Jane');
  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('1234');
  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('clickme')).click();
```

You are using `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` which is deprectaed. Try using`waitForAngularEnabled(true)`.

make the `BeforEach()` as

```
beforeEach(function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); // to tell protractor that this is a non- anularg page
    browser.get('http://be-docs-dev.xyz.local/');
  });
```

After moving to angular page make it as  `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);`.

Hope the above answer helps you...